# Layout design in react native

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

I am trying to design below layout in react native.

I am not able to draw horizontal line as shown above. 
Some how I have drawn but margin on the right is not being applied[image: LAYOUT IN REACT NATIVE]

> Code

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>
                        Search
                </Text>
                    <View style={styles.viewStyleForLine1}></View>
                </View>
```

> Style

```
viewStyleForLine1: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#cc0000',
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5,
        width:"100%"
    },
```

> More edit on centering the content

Here is how my View is

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>
             Search</Text>
            <View style={styles.viewStyleForLine1}></View>
            </View>
```

> Style

```
text: {
        marginTop: 16,
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#cc0000',
        marginLeft: 15
    },

    viewStyleForLine1: {
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#cc0000',
        marginLeft: 5,
        alignItems:"center",      
        marginRight: 15,
        alignSelf:"center",
        flex:1
    },
```

What modification I should do?

Comment: which content do you want to align center, the `Text` or the Line?

Comment: line in center with respect to text.

Comment: you can see this(https://snack.expo.io/@rns/bold-celery)  whether match your situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change the style `width: "100%"` to "flex:1". you want the right view to occupy the rest of width, then the "flex:1" means the rest of width belongs to it.it has a weight. the percentage you have to use in both components. the more tips about UI adapter you can read this [article](https://medium.com/@shanerudolfworktive/7-tips-to-develop-react-native-uis-for-all-screen-sizes-7ec5271be25c)

```
viewStyleForLine1: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#cc0000',
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5,
        flex:1
    },
```

Comment: Seems working solution, Can anything I can do to align it with center of text?

Comment: Surely, Will do. But can I do anything for center aligning of line?

Comment: when the flex-direction is `row`,  you want the vertical direction to align center, set the `alignItem:'center`, but the 'search' text also aligns center. you should split it two views, the line makes it in a direction column view:`<View><Text> <View><Line/></View<View>`